# Understanding snapshots in Ceph

Tags: snapshot, ceph

Our team is currently deciding whether to implement snapshotting on cephfs directories or not, and thus trying to understand the effects and performance issues caused by snapshots on the cluster.

Our main concern is "How will the cluster be affected when data is written to a file under a snapshot?". We were able to find out that Ceph uses a Copy-on-write mechanism to clone the snapshots, so my question is, for example, if I have a 1GB file under a snapshot and I append another 10MB of data to the file, then how much data will be copied because of the new write?

My understanding is that since Ceph stripes a file into multiple objects, only the object containing the last stripe_unit (assuming it's not completely filled) will be copied and the new data will be added to it, and then Ceph somehow manages to include the new object when I request the current version file and will include the old object when I request the file from the snapshot. Data copied = O(10MB), I mean it's in the order of data written, and a few metadata changes.

Or since Ceph now uses Bluestore as the storage layer, does it have even better optimisations (compared to the above case), like when editing the object corresponding to the last stripe_unit, will ceph just write the new data to a location in the disk and edit the metadata of the object to include the location of the new data, and also maintain snapshot-based versions of the metadata to provide us the file contents at previous points in time. Data copied/written = 10MB and some more metadata changes (compared to the above case).

Or is the case that Ceph will copy the whole file and edit the new copy of the file i.e. data copied is 1GB + 10MB. I am assuming this is not the case because it's clearly suboptimal for large files.

PS: Any resources on measuring the effect of snapshots on the cluster and any resources that explain the internals of Ceph snapshots will be very much appreciated. I've done extensive searching on the internet but couldn't find any relevant data. Tried reading the code but you guys can probably guess how it went.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the resources to understand the fundamentals of Ceph snapshots are as following:

- Chapter 9 namely "Storage Provisioning with Ceph" of book [Learning Ceph](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1787127915)
- Chapter "Planning for Ceph" in book [Mastering Ceph](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1789610702)

Furthermore, if you want to get Bluestore specific information of snapshots you may need to read following two resources as they explicitly explain Bluestore based snapshots:

- [File systems unfit as distributed storage backends: lessons from 10 years of Ceph evolution](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3341301.3359656)
- [The Case for Custom Storage Backends in Distributed Storage Systems](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3386362)

Comment: This can't be the accepted answer. Links provided lead to pages to either buy books, or to papers for which the subscription is needed. Stackoverflow provides engineers with answers or guidelines to specific problems, like the question stated.

Answer (score -1):

I had a same problem ahead and since I couldn't find specific answer I made an empirical test.
I created test pool so I can measure consumption per pool, and uploaded the same xml file repeatedly, with just 1 byte added at the end of file for each new version of the same file. File size is 5MB.
I made a new snapshot every time after saving new version (that means replacing the original file). I noticed that although cephfs reports no change in dir size (df), pool reports n times bigger consumption. 5MB file with 5 different versions take 25MB of pool space for snapshots (5 for the latest version in cephfs and 20 for additional 4 versions of file in snapshots).
That means that although only small part was appended, the copy of the whole file is saved for every new version. It is a bad news if you have a lot of big files that change a lot. I will test with much larger files and post an update.

UPDATE: test with 500MB file
The result is the same as with 5MB file. For every new file version I append just 1 line, replace the file in cephfs and make new snapshot.
Each time pool consumption increases for 500MB. Only my assumption about block size is wrong: there are ~1200 blocks for ~2.5GB, so block size is 2MB?